# Pg perl module does not build on OSX

Tags: macos, perl

I am trying without success to build the [Pg](http://search.cpan.org/~mergl/pgsql_perl5-1.9.0/Pg.pm) perl module. I set up the `POSTGRES_LIB` and `POSTGRES_INCLUDE` respectively to `/opt/local/lib/postgresql93` and `/opt/local/include/postgresql93`. But when I run `perl Makefile.pl` I get this error

```
Configuring Pg
Remember to actually read the README file !
please set environment variables POSTGRES_INCLUDE and POSTGRES_LIB !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you should use this module. It was last updated 15 years ago (info from the [Changes file](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/pgsql_perl5)) and it has [open bugs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=pgsql_perl5). But the most important thing that is has no likes on metacpan — it means that very few people use it.

I thinks that [DBD::Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RUDY/DBD-Pg-1.32/Pg.pm) is a better choice. It was last updates 11 years ago and it also [have open bugs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=DBD-Pg) but has a [lot of likes on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RUDY/DBD-Pg-1.32/Pg.pm) that means that it works well.

Comment: Yes I know, but apparently  [beancounter](https://github.com/jshy/Beancounter) without this module doesn't communicate with Postgres. And I need this in order to setup an historical stock database..

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to run all this app stack on some linux box? Are you planning to install in on mac os just to debug/improve or the production system will be mac os? In case it will be run on some linux server maybe you can not solve the problem with mac os installation.

Comment: On linux box (Arch) it runs without problems after installing the aforementioned module. I have planned to use Linux box as server. Now it is just a mere curiosity. Most important is that GTrader for doing check trading strategies is running ok on OSX. Thanks!